# Angular4 dynamic table reset values on previous created row

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table

I am creating a dynamic table which adds a row on click(). However, every add of the row resets the value of the previous row.

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
       <td><button type="button" (click)="addRow()">Add row </td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

// html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td><input name="something" type="text" [ngModel]="row.item.name </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

// component

```
...
this.item = {name: 'Superman'};

this.rows = [{
    item: this.item
}];

....
this.addRow() {
    this.rows.push({
        item: this.item
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] We just need to make the name of the input unique!

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
       <td><button type="button" (click)="addRow()">Add row </td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>

// html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
        <td><input name="something_{{i}}" type="text" [ngModel]="row.item.name </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

// component
...
this.item = {name: 'Superman'};

this.rows = [{
    item: this.item
}];

....
this.addRow() {
    this.rows.push({
        item: this.item
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're pushing same object reference in an array multiple times. So if you change `this.item` will effectively change the value in all newly added array element(since they carry the same object reference).

The solution would be, push clone object to an items array.

```
this.rows.push({
    item: Object.assign({}, this.item); //created clone
});
```